# Generate all partitions of integer array

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset, brute-force, data-partitioning

The Bell numbers count the number of partitions of a set. I want to generate all possible partitions of my integer array.

For example, I have the following integer array: `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. Then there are 15 partitions.

[image: all partitions]

Is there any simple way to complete my task? Or what is common algorithm?

Comment: Do you want the number of partitionings or the partitionings themselves?

Comment: @5gon12eder, I know number of partitionings. This is a table data. I want to get partitionings themselves.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to generate all possible (single) subsets, eg. in a recursive function? If you have that, make another level of recursiveness... Subsets and Partitions of the set without the current subset...

Comment: The issue with recursion is that you will get redundant values in your result set. I guess you need to use `std::set` and check at each level of recursion if you already found the partition you're at.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Lattice_of_partitions_of_an_order_4_set.svg